# Shell scripting: how to sort array in file txt

Tags: shell

I have a file txt
*for example:*

```
11 23 4 9  
5 2 17 25
```

*and the output that I want is:*

```
2 4 5 9   
11 17 23 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers in the file with [`sort -un`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | sort -un | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Of course we don't really know whether `-u` is what the OP wants..... Another strange point in the requirement is that the OP wants to have the output so that there are 4 numbers per line, which you would have to add to your solutions (for instance, by using *xargs*). In any case, the requirements are not specified well enough and the OP should be more precise, and present his own efforts, before we can think of a reasonable solution.

Comment: That is for the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sort -n | paste -d ' ' - - - -
2 4 5 9
11 17 23 25
```

`tr` changes all spaces into newlines and removes excess newlines from the input. This create a stream of numbers, one number per line, which is then sorted numerically and pasted into four space-separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

this gawk codes will work for the dynamic number of columns:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)a[++i]=$x}
     END{asort(a,b)
     for(x=1;x<=i;x++)printf "%s%s",b[x],x%NF==0?RS:FS,b[x]}' file
```